# Smart Contract Deployment issue

Tags: contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle-deployment

I am making a smart contract with a `Transfer` function.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success) {
        //checking whether sender has enough number of tokens
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        //Transfer of Token ownership
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to]+=_value;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender,_to,_value);
        return true;
}
```

Error:

```
  //     Replacing 'DappToken'
  //    ---------------------
  // Error: Error: Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

  // "DappToken" -- Invalid number of parameters for "Transfer". Got 1 expected 3!.

  //     at Object.run (C:\Users\rohit.mittal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-migrate\index.js:84:1)
  //     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  // Truffle v5.0.18 (core: 5.0.18)
  // Node v10.2.1
```

Comment: Check the number of parameters you are sending. Also if you can share your code it would be more helpful to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand your issue without having the piece of code where you call the `Transfer` function.

The error says that your `Transfer` function takes 3 inputs while you passed only 1 parameter thus it throw you that error.